# How to check if any elements of an array are not included in another array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm making a player vs computer Mastermind (the board game) program as part of learning Ruby.

*If  you don't know Mastermind, basically it's a two-player game where one player creates a code of four colours (i.e. "red red blue yellow") and the opponent tries to guess that code.*

The game initializes with a set of available colours and an empty code:

```
@@colours = ["RED", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "GREEN", "ORANGE", "WHITE"]
@code = []
```

I can ask the user to set a code like this:

```
puts "Please set your code:"
code = gets.chomp.downcase.split("")
@code << code
```

The user inputs the code like so: `rgby` => `code = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW"]`.

*(There will be a method which changes, i.e. "r" to "RED", please assume that happens somewhere in my program.)*

I want to make sure the player can only use colours included in `@@colours`, i.e. `pxgb` would not work.

Pseudo-code would be along the lines of:

> If all input colours are found in `@@colours`, update `@code`.

or conversely

> If any input colours are not found in `@@colours`, do not update `@code` (and possibly do something else).

How do I write this? I'm not too familiar with error handling so I was trying to do it with out but I'm willing to learn if that's the best way to go.

Comment: Are duplicates allowed, e.g. `["RED'", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN"]`?

Comment: Duplicates are allowed.

Comment: @Stefan, what is the wavelength of `"RED'"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland uhm, well, `'` most certainly denotes a complementary color. Yeah that's it, RED' is CYAN. Definitely not a typo ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following to check if `code` has only elements from `@@colours`

```
(code - @@colours).empty?
```

Above expression will be `true` if `code` contains only elements from `@@colours`, else it will be `false`.

---

PS: In the code sample in question, `code` is once shown as containing input from `gets` and another time shown as an array of processed inputs.  In the above solution, I am assuming `code = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `Set` object and `subset?` function.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

You can convert your arrays to Sets by using the `to_set` function on your array

Answer (score 0):

You could just subtract the allowed elements from the input. If the result isn't empty, then there was an element in the input that is not in the list of allowed values:

```
allowed = [1,2,3]

input = [1,2]
input - allowed #=> []

input = [1,5]
input - allow   #=> [5]
```

As a bonus this returns the element that is not allow and can be used in an error message.

Comment: it seems very similar with @WandMaker answer